# Add status_code to custom exception in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, exception

#### config/application.rb:

```
config.exceptions_app = self.routes

config.action_dispatch.rescue_responses.merge!(
  'Errors::UnauthorizedException' => :unauthorized
)
```

#### app/controllers/errors_controller.rb

```
class ErrorsController < ActionController::Base
  layout 'application'

  def show
    @exception = env["action_dispatch.exception"]
    @status_code = params[:code] || ActionDispatch::ExceptionWrapper.new(env, @exception).status_code
    render @status_code.to_s, :status => @status_code
  end
end
```

#### config/routes.rb

```
%w( 404 422 500 401 ).each do |code|
  get code, :to => 'errors#show', :code => code
end
```

What am I missing here? If I go to /:code, I get the correct response. If I go to a page where Rails will throw a 404 or a 500, I get the correct response. But if I try to `raise Errors::UnauthorizedException` I will get a 500 instead of a 401. How do I attach the status code I want to this exception?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the exact same situation and the fix was very simple in my case. I can't explain it any better, but depending on how and where you defined that Error class, it might be a "top-level Constant" (at least thats what my logs said).

So instead of:

```
config.action_dispatch.rescue_responses.merge!(
  'Errors::UnauthorizedException' => :unauthorized
)
```

do

```
config.action_dispatch.rescue_responses.merge!(
  'UnauthorizedException' => :unauthorized
)
```